# Print a leading '+' for positive numbers in printf

Tags: c, string, formatting, format, printf

I've a temperature conversion program as an assignment, which I've completed. The program has many `printf` statements in it which print the temperature. Now the negative temperatures are printed the way I want them but the positive temperatures are printed without a leading `+` sign.

Now what is the best way to get `printf` print a leading `+`sign for positive number. All I could think of is to change

```
printf("Min temp = %d\n",max_temp)
```

to

```
if(max_temp > 0)
    printf("+");
printf("Min temp = %d\n",max_temp)
```

But that calls for many changes in program :(

Another option is to write my own print function and put this logic there. What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 77):

You can use the `+` flag of [**printf**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) to print positive numbers with a leading `+` sign as:

```
printf("%+d %+d",10,-10); // prints +10 -10
```

Comment: a polite way to say RTFM (just kidding)

Comment: A follow-up question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69314212/330457

Answer (score 24):

Add the + flag. Here is an example.

```
int n;
printf("%+d", n);
```

(assuming n is an int - just replace %d for other numeric types)

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you meant to do the following thing,

```
double num1 = 1.;

// print num1 with leading "+";
printf("%s%lf\n",num1>0.?"+":"",num1);   // +1.000000
```